# Using botan argon2 command line tools

Tags: hash, passwords, botan, argon2-ffi

I'm trying to use argon2 for password hashing from within a C++ application.
The Botan library seems well regarded for this.
I have installed the library on my system via yum.

I'm trying to use the command line utilities provided to test the library.
Using the following command:

`botan gen_argon2 mypass`

I get output like this:

`$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=1,p=1$Wr2U4EazXMyIS3RJJczZ9Q$TE4xgLdvtLVNgia9wyrXpI+KSFkw6YJo2RR0yQVeahM`

I then want to verify this

`botan check_argon2 mypass $argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=1,p=1$Wr2U4EazXMyIS3RJJczZ9Q$TE4xgLdvtLVNgia9wyrXpI+KSFkw6YJo2RR0yQVeahM`

I get
`Password is NOT valid`

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried putting various parts of the output of gen_argon2 as the input to check_argon2 but always get NOT valid.

I've tried an online hash generator checker here:
https://argon2.online
This verifies the full hash `$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=1,p=1$dNxyyHX/WSojvaSwAEilwg$I9F/yzzMk/fclJIFNrkoSjP1WxVOI0lZJU1FTWRmxu0` as being correct
I've tried putting the hash in quotes to avoid bash interpreting any of it, but still no joy.

Update:
Calling the corresponding functions from C++ seems to work as expected, so maybe this is just a command line parsing issue.

I have more questions on the botan library but I'll post those separately

Comment: You mentioned you tried quoting, what quotes did you use? It works for me with single quotes `'...'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your shell may be escaping the `$` characters. Try wrapping your hash in single quotes on the command line.

Comment: As simple as that - Thanks.
I'd tried double quotes bot didn't think of single quotes. Looks like I need to brush up on my shell escaping rules.